# Dell Inspiron keyboard stopped working, PC now won't turn on

Tags: firmware

While working, the keyboard on my laptop stopped working, so I used the mouse to shut it down. But now the power button is continuously lit, and can't turn the computer on anymore. I'm pretty sure the computer is off because the fan isn't running and the screen is off. I'm using Windows 10.

**Edit:** Taking out the battery worked. Is there a way to avoid this problem in the future?

Comment: Take out the battery and replug?

Comment: My old HP has the same behaviour when the touchpad has its flatcable not properly plugged. Disassemble the notebook, carefully unplug the flatcable of your keyboard, then replug and secure it with the little hinge that secures the cable in place. After you have this done, it shouldn't happen anymore. If this continues to happen (and the problem *IS* the keyboard), the hinge may be damaged. You can isolate the issue, unplugging the internal keyboard and try turning the notebook on multiple times.

Comment: I fixed my broken hinge by both inserting the flatcable and a thin piece of plastic under or overlaying the flatcable (depends in which direction the contacts are faced). Caution: Don't do this, unless you are 100% sure it **IS** the hinge that is broken, because that's not the proper way to do it. You can use this "technique" to extend the lifetime of your motherboard a couple of months until you have money to buy another notebook (motherboard).

Comment: And I may also say that **I don't know** if your issue is the same as mine. I also don't take responsibility for any damage you make trying this.